# Netlogo: Can Netlogo set up an infinite number of turtles for only one specific patch?

Tags: netlogo, infinite

Can Netlogo set up an infinite number of turtles for only one specific patch? And the patch is road setting. This link is the image of that specific patch. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdBF0.jpg And the following is the sample code. However this is not compleated.

```
turtles-at 0 0 of patch min-pxcor 0 ; this is not compleated
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Turtles don't take up space, so as many as you need can fit on a single patch, but what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry goodgest, I still don't understand the actual *code* problem- if Bryan's answer doesn't get to what you're trying to do, pretend I don't know anything about "queuing theory" (or, don't pretend- I really don't) and reframe the question. Also, @Alan is right to point out that you have some 14 questions for which you have not accepted an answer (by clicking the check mark). You should do so to indicate that the question has been successfully answered and so that future users with similar questions know if a solution worked.

Comment: @ Luke C The model I have is by default a road setting. Therefore, it seems that only one turtle can be put in one patch. I want to set a patch that is infinite number of turtles will put in one specific patch (coordinates are (0, 0)) like the image. I would like to know how to set up the patche to contain infinite number of turtles. That information was not written anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Bryan's answer, there is no theoretical restriction on the number of turtles in a single patch, although your *computer* will have a limit- the more turtles in your model (on any patch) the more memory your model will use. So the short answer is, as far as I know, there is no way to just say to Netlogo, "Spawn infinite turtles on this patch."

If, however, by infinite you really just want enough turtles that you won't run out of them for specific interactions, you could probably get by either by just spawning a large number on that patch or by just sprouting more as needed (my preference).

For the first option, you can have a bunch of turtles on the same patch:

```
to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  ask patch 0 0 [
    sprout 10000
  ]
  ask patch 0 0 [
    print count turtles-here
  ]
end
```

Alternatively, if your turtles on the patch get used up or become unavailable in some way, just have more sprout as needed to keep your numbers high enough for what you're trying to do. Here's an example where red turtles walk to a patch with "infinite" (1000) blue turtles, link to one of the blue turtles, and take them away. However, at the end of each tick, the "infinite" patch checks if there are fewer than 1000 `turtles-here`. If there are, it spawns enough turtles to bring that count back up to 1000. Try this code in a new file:

```
to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  infinite-sprout
  source-sprout

end

to go

  ask turtles with [ color = red ] [
    fd 0.5
    if any? ( turtles-on patch-ahead 1 ) with [ color = blue ] [
      create-link-with one-of turtles-on patch-ahead 1 [
        tie
      ]        
      set color green        
    ]
  ]
  ask turtles with [color = green] [
    move-to patch-right-and-ahead 90 1
    if pycor = max-pycor [
      ask link-neighbors [ 
        die
      ]
      die
    ]
  ]

  infinite-sprout
  source-sprout
  tick

end


to source-sprout
  ask patch max-pxcor 0 [
    if not any? turtles-here and random 3 = 1 [
      sprout 1 [
        set shape "arrow"
        set color red
        set heading 270
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to infinite-sprout
  ask patch 0 0 [
    if count turtles-here < 1000 [
      sprout ( 1000 - count turtles-here) [
        set shape "circle"
        set color blue
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Then set up your interface like this: 
[image]

If you run that model for a while, you will see that at the end of every tick, the `count turtles` of patch 0 0 is brought back up to 1000, effectively giving you an infinite source of turtles that you can "use up." Does that accomplish what you need?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It takes a bit while, but I will test it with the sample program. I need 1000 turtles data in one plot. So I will add stop sintax to privent the crash computer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly sure what you're asking, but there is no limit to the number of turtles that can be on a patch (save the limit imposed by your computer's memory).

Also, the code you're probably looking for is something like:

```
turtles-on patch 0 0
```

for the left patch and

```
turtles-on patch 1 0
```

for the right patch.